# logging 2 files every day with log4net

Tags: logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

So what I wanna do is log two separate files on a daily basis. I'm new to log4net so what I did was usual stuff.. google and google until it works :) and everything works fine, but I can't make it log files every day.

Here is my code:

web.config:

```xml
<log4net>
    <appender type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" name="AllApp">
        <file value="C:\\myLogs\\App.log" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
        <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c [%x] - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" name="ServiceLog">
        <file value="C:\\myLogs\\ServiceLog.log" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
        <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c [%x] - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <priority value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="AllApp" />
    </root>
    <logger name="ServiceLog">
        <priority value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="ServiceLog" />
    </logger>
</log4net>
```

and in my log class:

```cs
public static class LogProvider
{
    static ILog log;

    static LogProvider()
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        log = LogManager.GetLogger("ServiceLog");
    }
```

I'm probably doing something wrong but whatever I try it ends up in failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i guess there was no problem at all.. i just wasnt familiar with ways of date logging in log4net.. what log4net does is it leaves todays log undated (for example.. all this i log today will be stored in App.log, but tomorrow log4net will shift todays logs to App.logYYYYMMDD)

Comment: use <staticLogFileName value="false" /> and it will behave more like you would expect it...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the rolling style like this:

```
<rollingStyle value="Date" />
```

Comment: tried that.. didnt work.. in fact, that was the first thing i tried :) than i switched to Composite because i thought maybe value="Date" cant be used with named files..